# Equation of curves defined by following vector function in terms of variable $t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Write an equation for a surface which  contain the curves defined by following vector function

> $r(t)=\bigg<3t,e^{t},1-t^2\bigg>$

What i try:

Campare with $r(t)=\bigg<x,y,z\bigg>$

We get $x=3t,y=e^{t},z=1-t^2$

$$9z=9-(3t)^2=9-x^2\Longrightarrow 9z=1-x^2$$

I did not understand what is the use of $y$ coordinate Here. Help me please . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the $y$ coordinate. The equation you found describes a set which obviously contains the curve. Now why is it a surface ? It depends on what you definition of a surface is but intuitively, what can we say? In the plane $y=y_0$, the equation describes a parabola. Since this parabola is the same whatever the value of $y_0$ is, the surface is the union of all the possible translations of this parabola along the $y$ axis, and as a result it is indeed a surface. Does that answer your question?

Roughly speaking (I say that because there are some degenerate case in which this is not true), a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ described by $k \in [\![0,n]\!]$ non-redundant scalar equations is of dimension $n-k$. Here, you are in dimension 3 and your set is described by one scalar equation so it is of dimension 2 and it is a surface. Note that the notion of 'dimension' that I refer to here is a more general notion than the dimension of vector spaces. The concept that is behind it is differentiable manifold, but it is a somewhat advanced domain.

Comment: Thanks DodoDuQuercy. But still have some doubt.(less clear)

Answer (score 2):

A surface in 3D can be given by an equation, while a curve is given by two independent equations.

Your curve satisfies the equations $9z=9-x^2$ and $y=e^{x/3}$. The first equation alone gives you a surface which contains the curve. The fact that the generating equation for this surface does not contain $y$ just means that the surface has a translational symmetry in the $y$ direction. This is similar to the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ which has a translational symmetry in the $z$ direction.

It may seem odd that you did not have to know $y(t)$, but this is just a manifestation of the fact that there are *many* surfaces containing this curve. The full parameterization of the curve contains extra information which we don't have to use: any two coordinates could have sufficed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is slightly different way to see this  curve as the intersection curve of two surfaces.

Indeed, by elimination of $t$ between equation (a) and equation (c), we obtain relationship (A), whereas elimination of $t$ between equation (a) and equation (b) gives relationship (B) below

$$\begin{cases}z&=&1−(x^2)/9& \ \ \ (A)\\ y&=&e^{x/3}& \ \ \ (B)\end{cases} \tag{1}$$

Otherwise said the curve is the intersection curve of surfaces with equations (A) and (B) which are **(generalized) cylinders** as shown on the figure below.

Therefore, the conclusion is that either
(1)(A) or (1)(B) provides an answer to your question.

**More generally**, if we consider equations (1)(A) and (1)(B) written under the form

$$\begin{cases}z-1+(x^2)/9&=&0& \ \ \ (A)\\ y-e^{x/3}&=&0& \ \ \ (B)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

any linear combination of these equations, for example :

$$3(z-1+(x^2)/9)+4(y-e^{x/3})=0$$

is also a solution (it will correspond to a surface which is "in-between" the two represented surfaces).

[image]